# Put $f(z)=\cos({\frac{1}{z-1}})$ as a complex series around $0$. Find the convergence radius.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Here's my try on this one:

> Put $f(z)=\cos({\frac{1}{z-1}})$ as a complex series around $0$. Find the convergence radius.

Here's what I did so far:

> $\cos({\frac{1}{z-1}})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{(z-1)^{2n}}}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{(z-1)^{2n}(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{(w)^{2n}(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{(t)^{-n}(2n)!},$
>
> with $z-1=w$ and $w^{-2}=t$.
>
> So from here, we find the radius of convergence:
>
> $\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n)!}{(2n+2)!\cdot (-1)^n}}=0\implies R=\infty.$

Is this right? Maybe I missed something or did something wrong and I can't see it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since $f$ is holomorphic on a disk around $0$ and it has a unique singularity at $1$, the radius of convergence of the *power series expansion* must be $1$.

Comment: You need to compute the radius of convergence of the power series *at the origin*, and it is not really pratical to use the Laurent series at $z=1$. $z=1$ is the only singularity of the given function (an essential singularity), hence the radius of convergence of the power series at the origin is $1$, as already remarked by egreg.